# why am I getting a seg fault for this c implementation of a hash table?

Tags: c

I'm working through an assignment for an at-your-own-pace course and am tasked with building out a vector and hashset. One of the provided tests builds a hashtable using my implementation of a hashset and in the running of the test, I'm getting a segfault. I was wondering what the issue is for this code:

```
#include "hashset.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "vector.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int logicallength;
  int alloclength;
  void *elems;
  int elemSize;
  VectorFreeFunction freeFn;
} vector;
typedef struct
{
    int elemSize;
    int numBuckets;
    HashSetHashFunction hashfn;
    HashSetCompareFunction comparefn;
    HashSetFreeFunction freefn;
    void *elems;
} hashset;

void HashSetNew(hashset *h, int elemSize, int numBuckets,
                HashSetHashFunction hashfn, HashSetCompareFunction comparefn, HashSetFreeFunction freefn)
{
    assert(comparefn != NULL && hashfn != NULL);
    h->comparefn = comparefn;
    h->hashfn = hashfn;
    h->numBuckets = numBuckets;
    h->elemSize = elemSize;
    h->freefn = freefn;
    h->elems = malloc(numBuckets * sizeof(vector));
    for (int i = 0; i < numBuckets; i++)
    {
        VectorNew(&h->elems[i], elemSize, freefn, 0);
    }
}

int HashSetCount(const hashset *h)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < h->numBuckets; i++)
    {
        count += VectorLength(&h->elems[h->hashfn(i, h->numBuckets)]);
    }
    return count;
}

void HashSetEnter(hashset *h, const void *elemAddr)
{
    assert(h != NULL);
    assert(elemAddr != NULL);
    int bucketI = h->hashfn(elemAddr, h->numBuckets);
    assert(bucketI >= 0 && bucketI < h->numBuckets);
    vector *bucket = &h->elems[bucketI];
    int i = VectorSearch(bucket, elemAddr, h->comparefn, 0, false);
    i >= 0 ? VectorReplace(bucket, elemAddr, i) : VectorAppend(bucket, elemAddr);
}

void *HashSetLookup(const hashset *h, const void *elemAddr)
{
    assert(h != NULL);
    assert(elemAddr != NULL);
    int bucketI = h->hashfn(elemAddr, h->numBuckets);
    assert(bucketI >= 0 && bucketI < h->numBuckets);
    vector *bucket = &h->elems[bucketI];
    int i = VectorSearch(bucket, elemAddr, h->comparefn, 0, false);
    return i < 0 ? NULL : &bucket->elems[i];
}

void VectorNew(vector *v, int elemSize, VectorFreeFunction freeFn, int initialAllocation)
{
    v->logicallength = 0;
    v->alloclength = initialAllocation > 0 ? initialAllocation : 1;
    v->elemSize = elemSize;
    v->elems = malloc(v->alloclength * elemSize);
    v->freeFn = freeFn;
    assert(v->elems != NULL);
}

void VectorDispose(vector *v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v->logicallength; i++)
    {
        void *elem = v->elems + i * v->elemSize;
        if (v->freeFn != NULL)
        {
            v->freeFn((char *)elem);
        }
    }
    free(v->elems);
}

int VectorLength(const vector *v)
{
    return v->logicallength;
}

void *VectorNth(const vector *v, int position)
{
    /*
     * Returns a pointer to the element numbered position in the vector.
     * Numbering begins with 0.  An assert is raised if n is less than 0 or greater
     * than the logical length minus 1.  Note this function returns a pointer into
     * the vector's storage, so the pointer should be used with care.
     * This method must operate in constant time.
     */
    assert(position >= 0 && position <= v->logicallength - 1);
    return v->elems + (position * v->elemSize);
}

void VectorReplace(vector *v, const void *elemAddr, int position)
{
    assert(position >= 0 && position <= v->logicallength);
    void *to = v->elems + position * v->elemSize;
    assert(to != NULL);
    if (v->freeFn != NULL)
    {
        v->freeFn(to);
    }
    memcpy(to, elemAddr, v->elemSize);
}

static void PrintChar(void *elem, void *fp)
{
    fprintf((FILE *)fp, "%c", *(char *)elem);
    fflush((FILE *)fp);
}

void VectorInsert(vector *v, const void *elemAddr, int position)
{
    assert(position >= 0 && position <= v->logicallength);
    v->alloclength++;
    v->logicallength++;
    realloc(v->elems, v->alloclength * sizeof(void *));
    assert(v->elems != NULL);
    void *from = v->elems + position * v->elemSize;
    void *to = from + v->elemSize;
    VectorMap(v, PrintChar, stdout);
    memmove(to, from, v->logicallength - position);
    memcpy(from, elemAddr, v->elemSize);
}

void VectorAppend(vector *v, const void *elemAddr)
{
    if (v->alloclength == 0)
    {
        v->alloclength = 1;
        v->elems = realloc(v->elems, v->alloclength * sizeof(void *));
    }
    if (v->logicallength == v->alloclength)
    {
        v->alloclength *= 2;
        v->elems = realloc(v->elems, v->alloclength * sizeof(void *));
        assert(v->elems != NULL);
    }
    void *target = (char *)v->elems + v->logicallength * v->elemSize;
    memcpy(target, elemAddr, v->elemSize);
    v->logicallength++;
}

void VectorDelete(vector *v, int position)
{
    /*
     * An assert is raised if position is less than 0 or greater than the logical length
     * minus one.  All the elements after the specified position will be shifted over to fill
     * the gap.  This method runs in linear time.  It does not shrink the
     * allocated size of the vector when an element is deleted; the vector just
     * stays over-allocated.
     */
    assert(position >= 0 && position < v->logicallength);
    void *from = (char *)v->elems + (position + 1) * v->elemSize;
    void *to = from - v->elemSize;
    memmove(to, from, (v->logicallength - (position + 1)) * v->elemSize);
    v->logicallength--;
}

void VectorSort(vector *v, VectorCompareFunction compare)
{
    qsort(v->elems, v->logicallength, v->elemSize, compare);
}

void VectorMap(vector *v, VectorMapFunction mapFn, void *auxData)
{
    assert(mapFn != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < v->logicallength; i++)
    {
        mapFn((v->elems + i * v->elemSize), auxData);
    }
}

static const int kNotFound = -1;
int VectorSearch(const vector *v, const void *key, VectorCompareFunction searchFn, int startIndex, bool isSorted)
{
    if (isSorted)
    {
        char *firstChar = v->elems + startIndex * v->elemSize;
        char *offset = (int *)bsearch(key, firstChar, v->logicallength, v->elemSize, searchFn);
        if (offset == NULL)
        {
            return kNotFound;
        }
        return (offset - firstChar) / v->elemSize;
    }
    for (int i = startIndex; i < v->logicallength; i++)
    {
        const void *ch = v->elems + i * v->elemSize;
        if (searchFn(key, ch) == 0)
        {
            return i / v->elemSize;
        }
    }
    return kNotFound;
}
```

I tried running through gdb and printing out the state of some of the intermediate variables to no avail like

```
(gdb) print *(vector*)h->elems
$10 = {logicallength = 0, alloclength = 65536, elems = 0x4056300000, elemSize = 524288, freeFn = 0x0}
(gdb) print *(vector*)(h->elems + elemSize)
$11 = {logicallength = 1445986304, alloclength = 64, elems = 0x80000, elemSize = 0, freeFn = 0x0}
(gdb) print *(vector*)(h->elems + elemSize * 2)
$12 = {logicallength = 524288, alloclength = 0, elems = 0x0, elemSize = 0, freeFn = 0x0}
(gdb) print *(vector*)(h->elems + (elemSize * 2))
$13 = {logicallength = 524288, alloclength = 0, elems = 0x0, elemSize = 0, freeFn = 0x0}
```

The function that sets all of this off is as follows:

```
const int kNumBuckets = 26;

struct frequency
{
  char ch;         // a particular letter
  int occurrences; // the number of times it occurs
};
static int HashFrequency(const void *elem, int numBuckets)
{
  struct frequency *freq = (struct frequency *)elem;
  return (freq->ch % numBuckets);
}

static int CompareLetter(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)
{
  struct frequency *freq1 = (struct frequency *)elem1;
  struct frequency *freq2 = (struct frequency *)elem2;
  return (freq1->ch - freq2->ch);
}

static void TestHashTable(void)
{
  hashset counts;
  vector sortedCounts;

  HashSetNew(&counts, sizeof(struct frequency), kNumBuckets, HashFrequency, CompareLetter, NULL);
  BuildTableOfLetterCounts(&counts);
}

static void BuildTableOfLetterCounts(hashset *counts)
{
  struct frequency localFreq, *found;
  int ch;
  FILE *fp = fopen("hashsettest.c", "r"); // open self as file

  assert(fp != NULL);
  while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
    if (isalpha(ch))
    { // only count letters
      localFreq.ch = tolower(ch);
      localFreq.occurrences = 1;

      // See if we already have an entry for this char
      found = (struct frequency *)HashSetLookup(counts, &localFreq);
      if (found != NULL) // increment if already there
        localFreq.occurrences = found->occurrences + 1;
      HashSetEnter(counts, &localFreq); // enter should overwrite if needed
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
}
int main(int ununsed, char **alsoUnused)
{
  TestHashTable();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how I can reduce this to a simpler example. Thank you.

**EDIT: I was able to identify a couple errors, each one uncovering the next. My question is now why?**

the cause for the issue for this post was due to passing 0 as the initial allocation size

```
VectorNew(&h->elems[i], elemSize, freefn, 0);
```

with the interface of `VectorNew` being `void VectorNew(vector *v, int elemSize, VectorFreeFunction freefn, int initialAllocation);` (implementation can be found above)

The smallest value that it accepts seems to be 4 and I'm wondering why that is. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a program instead of a couple of snippets (i.e. [mre]).

Comment: There is a lot of code posted... but still not enough to compile the code. Post the missing code. With the code missing it's hard to help but this `vector *bucket = &h->elems[bucketI];` looks wrong. Didn't you get a warning? Did you compile with options like `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` ?

Comment: Also `void *from = (char *)v->elems + (position + 1) * v->elemSize;
    void *to = from - v->elemSize;` looks wrong. Warnings?

Comment: `realloc(v->elems, v->alloclength * sizeof(void *));` is for sure wrong.

Comment: Before considering any kind of debug, you must do 1) Use compiler options that enables all warnings (at least `-Wall -Wextra`). 2) Treat all warnings as errors, i.e `-Werror`. Only when you have a clean compile (i.e. no warnings at all), it's time to run the program.

Comment: @SupportUkraine thank you. I tried to follow Allan Wind's recommendation for submitting a minimal reproducible example, but while doing so, I seemed to have left out essential parts. I'll update it

Comment: Please step through it with your debugger and narrow down the line causing the seg fault.

Comment: @reactor And make sure it can compile **without any warnings** when compiling like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ...`  (or similar options for your compiler). Pizza and beer say that you'll find several bugs while cleaning up warnings.

Comment: "the cause for the issue for this post was due to passing 0 as the initial allocation size" I doubt that is the root cause. It may trigger the bug but the bug is in some other code... But again... as the posted code won't compile due to missing code, it's hard to help.